# dataadapter update method not working

Tags: sql, winforms, ado.net, dataadapter

I have a `DataSet` which I'm trying to use to update an sql db.

When I call the update method of the dataset's data adapter method. The backend db does not get updated.

To further test the problem I created a variable called `rowsAffected` which is:

```
int rowsAffected = private_EnrolleeTableAdapter1.Update(enrollee);
```

The variable returns 1 when I run the code but the databse is not updated.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Code is included below:

```
//Create new employee record(row) on Private_Enrollee table in database
HMODataSet.Private_EnrolleeRow enrollee = HMODataSet.Private_Enrollee.NewPrivate_EnrolleeRow();
enrollee.Title = title;
enrollee.Firstname = firstname;
enrollee.Othername = middlename;
enrollee.Surname = surname;
enrollee.Sex = sex;
enrollee.Date_of_Birth = dateofbirth;
enrollee.Office_Tel = officetel;
enrollee.Residential_Tel = restel;
enrollee.Mobile_Tel = mobtel;
enrollee.Email_Address = email;
enrollee.Marital_Status = maritalstatus;
enrollee.Occupation = occupation;
enrollee.NextOfKin_Name = nextofkin;
enrollee.Relationship = relationship;
enrollee.Next_of_Kin_Address = address;
enrollee.Next_of_Kin_Telephone_No = nextofkintelno;
enrollee.Address = address;
enrollee.Town = town;
enrollee.City = city;
enrollee.State = state;
enrollee.Country = country;
enrollee.Hospital = healthcareprovider;
enrollee.Proposed_Plan_Type = proposedinsuranceplan;
enrollee.Blood_Group = bloodgroup;
enrollee.Genotype = genotype;
enrollee.Pre_Informed_Illness = preinformedillness;
enrollee.Existing_Chronic_Illness = chronicdisease;
enrollee.Enrollee_Type = enrolleetypeid;
enrollee.Enrollee_Type_ID = enrolleetypeid;
enrollee.Occupation = occupation;
enrollee.Designation = designation;
enrollee.Employer = employer;

HMODataSet.Private_Enrollee.AddPrivate_EnrolleeRow(enrollee);

int rowsAffected = private_EnrolleeTableAdapter1.Update(enrollee);

HMODataSet.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: you could use sql server profiler to see what is actually executed on the database ... something gets executed, otherwise rowsAffected wouldn't be 1 ... maybe a new row gets inserted?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I found the problem. I was looking at the original DB instead of the locally stored one on the project. I have one more question though. What are the merits or demerits of using a locally stored DB as opposed to one stored with sqlexpress. Like say I wanted to compile the project as an installable. Would it make a difference if the database file was stored locally or not? Or would VS automatically load a copy of our data source for us?